# Glossary name is printed over glossary definition

Tags: glossaries, overleaf, printing

I want to use the `glossaries` package in the `IEEEtran` class in latex, but have problems in using it:

[image: glossary]

Latex:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
final,
oneside,
onecolumn,
paper=A4,
abstract=true,
headings=small
]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{geotagging}
{
    name={Geotagging},
    description={Hinzufügen von Metadaten wie Breiten- und Längenkoordinaten zur geografischen Identifizierung zu verschiedenen Medien}
}

\begin{document}

\gls{geotagging}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

As you can see, my latex code is very simple. Therefore, I'm not sure what the problem is, since I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: you need to insert a documentclass in your LaTeX file : \documentclass{article} \usepackage{glossaries} ...

Comment: please make your code snippet compilable!